# How to highlight a textview when mp audio is 3s to 5s?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a situation in my app where I have `TextView` and `audio`. when `audio` is started no letter is highlighted but when `audio` is at 3rd second `TextView` highlighted and when `audio` is at 5th second `TextView` unhighlighted.

Here is my `TextView` code with `audio` when I click on `TextView` it executes this given code but couldn't get what I need.

```
try {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        mp.reset();
        //p5_1_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p6_1.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        while (mp.getDuration() < 1.5) {
            p5_1_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why `mp.getDuration() < 1.5`? `MediaPlayer.getDuration()` returns duration in milliseconds, so it should be `3000` milliseconds.

Comment: i already tried this is not highlighting the textview for 3 seconds just playing whole audio

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the code checks the condition in `while` loop before the duration is more than three seconds. I'm afraid I don't know the most optimum solution but one work around is to do something like this https://pastebin.com/dJS3BwcA  Thanks :)